# How to concatenate string keys in Grunt config in order to build dynamic Keys

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript, gruntjs

Hi I stumbled over the problem that you cannot define dynamic keys for object in JavaScript and thus not in CoffeeScript when using object syntax. So

```
{
    "a dynamic" + " key": 1
}
```

or

```
"#{INTERPOLATED} key": 1
```

is invalid JS/CoffeeScript code.

How to deal with that when writing grunt configs? Usually those are defined using only the object literal syntax. Can it be avoided to store information inside the keys (e.g. for grunt plugins that have a configuration like `"output-file-name": "input-file-name"`). Or do people define an object literal as config and then add dynamic keys wherever needed with the `[]`-syntax?

Comment: *Or do people define an object literal as config and then add dynamic keys wherever needed with the []-syntax?* - Thats what I always do.

Comment: Usually you can use `src: "input-file-name", dest: "output-file-name"` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use dynamic keys in your object literals, have a look at LiveScript, a CoffeeScript-like language, which lets you do it natively :

http://livescript.net/#literals-objects

```
obj =
  "#variable": 234
  (person.eye-color): false
```